# Python prgram won't buil d after renaming it

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, geany

I've setup Geany a long time ago to compile my Python program on my Windows machine which it then sends to my Pi via scp. It still works fine - but if I take the same file and rename it, it refuses to do it.

I get "scp: /home/pi/scripts/APC2.py: Permission denied" from the Compiler in the MEssage window

And really don't want all my programs called the same thing.

I basically can't remember how I did the setup and can't find it anywhere on the internet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the link again:
http://www.python-exemplary.com/index_en.php?inhalt_links=navigation_en.inc.php&inhalt_mitte=raspi/en/installation.inc.php

Also my permissions for the new file were incorrect as Geany sends the file to /home/pi/scripts and I log in as root and not the pi user.